# Rear brake howls when leaving a stop light

Tags: brake-rotor

I get a noise comming from the rear of my truck when leaving a stop light. It only occurs for a few seconds until I reach 10-15 MPH. If I tap the brakes it stops but comes back as long as I'm going below 15 MPH.

Comment: Please provide more information about the vehicle you are describing; year, make, model, mileage, etc. When was the last time the brakes were serviced?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged 'brake-rotor' I am assuming you have rear disk brakes.

The noise could be caused by a seized rear caliper. The seized caliper will cause the pads to drag on the rotor, leading excessive vibration and noise. The sound goes away over 15 mph either because the friction has caused enough heat to un-stick the caliper, the rotor has provided enough force to knock the pad and caliper piston away from the rotor, the frequency of the vibration is no longer audible, or a mix and match of the three.

An easy way to check is to put your hand *near* the rotor after driving, and comparing the heat to the other side of the truck. If one side is noticeably hotter, that caliper is likely seized.

You may be able to fix the issue by removing the guide pins/boots, cleaning everything with brake clean, and reassembling the caliper with fresh grease. You may need new pads as well depending on how long this has been happening.